# Applying a function to all template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to make a function that finds an element by id and deletes it from static vectors in some types.

```
template<typename First>
void RemoveComponentByID(EntityID ID)
{
    auto element = binary_find(First::Array.begin(), First::Array.end(), ID);
    First::Array.erase(element);
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void RemoveComponentByID(EntityID ID)
{
    auto element = binary_find(First::Array.begin(), First::Array.end(), ID);
    First::Array.erase(element);
    RemoveComponentByID<Rest...>(ID);
}
```

But when I call the function `RemoveComponentByID<Vector3s,Textures>(id);`
The error " 'RemoveComponentByID' : ambiguous function call to overloaded function" pops up.
Why is that?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For overload resolution, there is a tie breaker between

- `template <typename T> void foo(T);`
- `template <typename T, typename ...Ts> void foo(T, Ts...);`

in favour to the non variadic,
but it is not the cas when those template are not part of function argument as you.

So, neither of

- `template <typename T> void bar();`
- `template <typename T, typename ...Ts> void bar();`

is more specialized, thus the ambiguous call for `bar<SomeType>()`.

You might do (C++17):

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void RemoveComponentByID(EntityID ID)
{
    auto element = binary_find(First::Array.begin(), First::Array.end(), ID);
    First::Array.erase(element);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Rest) > 0) {
        RemoveComponentByID<Rest...>(ID);
    }
}
```

or, without recursion:

```
template<typename T>
void RemoveComponentByIDImpl(EntityID ID)
{
    auto element = binary_find(T::Array.begin(), T::Array.end(), ID);
    T::Array.erase(element);
}

template<typename... Ts>
void RemoveComponentByID(EntityID ID)
{
    (RemoveComponentByIDImpl<Ts>(ID), ...);
}
```